# Understanding nested >> in a template function call

Tags: c++, templates

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct A
{
    constexpr int operator[](int a)
    {
        return a;
    }

    constexpr operator int()
    {
        return 1;
    }
} a;

template <int a>
int foo()
{
    return a;
};

int main(){ cout << foo<a[4 >> 1]>() << endl; }
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f8e148415db7fefa)**

The thing is the Standard said `N4286::14.2/3 [temp.names]`

> Similarly, the first non-nested `>>` is treated as two consecutive but
>   distinct `>` tokens, the first of which is taken as the end of the
>   template-argument-list and completes the template-id.

Where the definition of the nested << is the following `N4286::14.2/3 [temp.names]` (footnote 137):

> A `>` that encloses the `type-id` of a `dynamic_cast`, `static_cast`,
>   `reinterpret_cast` or `const_cast`, or which encloses the
>   template-arguments of a subsequent template-id, is considered nested
>   for the purpose of this description.

In my case `>>` is non-nested, therefore the first `<` should have been considered as the end of the template arguments. But it's not true, actually. Why?

Comment: Footnote 137 is not the definition of "nested"; it clarifies that in those situations the `>` is considered nested, not that *only* those `>` are nested.

Comment: Also, http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#579

Comment: @T.C. This issue is almost 9 years old and it still stay in the open status. So, the issue in my question is not currently resolvable under the current working draft, is it? BTW, both clang and g++ accept the code from the issue http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1bbec55c13532461